# An issue with the logic in the code using the Scanner object

Tags: java

I'm getting frustrated with something really basic here.. scanner just isn't doing what I want and I don't know why, I'd be really grateful if someone could help me

so i'm trying to program a a basic inventory and I want a scanner to check if a valid builder name has been entered. A string variable stores the user entered word, if an invalid builder name was entered I just want that string variable to be equal to "ANY". What is happening is - the string comes out correct (in capitals as I wanted) AS WELL as "Any", which it shouldn't!, when something invalid is entered, nothing is printed (and it should print "Any")

i've made a simple SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SSCCE {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a builder name: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //scan.useDelimiter("\\z"); // count a blank entry (end of input)

        String entry_1 = scan.next();


        if (entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("FENDER")
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("MARTIN")
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("GIBSON")
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("COLLINGS")
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("OLSON")
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("RYAN") 
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("PRS")) 
        {
            entry_1 = entry_1.toUpperCase();

            System.out.println(entry_1);
        }


    //  if (entry_1.equals(entry_1.toLowerCase())
    //          || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase(entry_1)
    //          && (entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("FENDER")
    //                  || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("MARTIN")
    //                  || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("GIBSON")
    //                  || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("COLLINGS")
    //                  || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("OLSON")
    //                  || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("RYAN") || entry_1
    //                      .equalsIgnoreCase("PRS"))) 
    //  {
    //      entry_1 = entry_1.toUpperCase();
    //  }

        if (!entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("FENDER")
                || !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("MARTIN")
                || !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("GIBSON")
                || !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("COLLINGS")
                || !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("OLSON")
                || !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("RYAN")
                || !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("PRS")) {

            entry_1 = "ANY";

            System.out.println(entry_1);
        }   
    }

}
```

edit:
thanks for all responses, now i'm just having a problem with scan.useDelimiter("\z");
when nothing is entered it should say "ANY" and so it does, but now it will always say "ANY" even for correct entry

Comment: use trim() to remove empty spaces of input. maybe it will help. Plus a programming advice, never use multiple if's when you can replace them with one if-else loop. It reduces the CPU overhead drastically in case of large programs.

Comment: @ADi What's an `if-else loop`?

Comment: @nhgrif In C if you are using a if followed by else loop, it has different working mechanism over only a set of if's. For each if, it searches else, which has some overhead. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @nhgrif sorry, my bad, It's a block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second `if`, it's guaranteed that `entry_1` isn't one case OR it isn't another case OR...  The logic is incorrect.  You want "and", with `&&`:

```
if (!entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("FENDER")
        && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("MARTIN")
        && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("GIBSON")
        && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("COLLINGS")
        && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("OLSON")
        && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("RYAN")
        && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("PRS")) {

    entry_1 = "ANY";

    System.out.println(entry_1);
}
```

However, it would have been simpler to attach it to the first `if` condition as an `else`:

```
if (entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("FENDER")
                    || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("MARTIN")
                    || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("GIBSON")
                    || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("COLLINGS")
                    || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("OLSON")
                    || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("RYAN") 
                    || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("PRS")) 
{
    entry_1 = entry_1.toUpperCase();

    System.out.println(entry_1);
}
else
{
    entry_1 = "ANY";

    System.out.println(entry_1);
}
```

Comment: yes you are right, thank u, someone else has also posted the same answer (@ the same time :D)

Comment: @Conor Yes, people posted at about the same time.  But I posted what the problem with the logic was _and_ the `else` alternative, from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Your second if statement, where you're checking `!entry_1`, etc. should use `&&` rather than `||`.

`"FENDER"` will return `true` for `!entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("MARTIN");` etc, and in a list of `||` comparisons, only one of them has to be `true` to make the whole thing return `true`.

Comment: ... or just use an `else` after the first if statement, and avoid doing all that logic a second time.

Comment: Yea, that too.  But that answer misses the logic problem that he has that could rear its head again in the future when `else` isn't an option necessarily.  Moreover, he may not necessarily want to execute these things in this order.

Comment: Right. If there's one thing I remember from `CSC1001 - Concepts of Computer Science` it's that `(a || b || c) == !(!a && !b && !c)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change whole of second if condition with else:

```
if (entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("FENDER")
                            || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("MARTIN")
                            || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("GIBSON")
                            || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("COLLINGS")
                            || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("OLSON")
                            || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("RYAN") 
                            || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("PRS")) 
            {
                entry_1 = entry_1.toUpperCase();

                System.out.println(entry_1);
            }

            else {

                entry_1 = "ANY";

                System.out.println(entry_1);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your second if statement from using `||` to `&&`:

```
if (!entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("FENDER")
                    && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("MARTIN")
                    && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("GIBSON")
                    && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("COLLINGS")
                    && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("OLSON")
                    && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("RYAN")
                    && !entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("PRS")) {
```

If you use `||` only one of the continues needs to be true for the if statement itself to be true and cause `ANY` to display as the output. With `&&` *all* the statements must evaluate for true before the if statement will execute and display `ANY`

Answer (score 0):

In the second if () use && not ||. That's all ;)